# Turtle graphics crashing

Tags: lambda, keyboard, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Help, i'm trying to make a turtle graphics program that uses keyboard to control the direction of the turtle but every time i open it, it keeps crashing!!

```
import keyboard
from turtle import *
keyboard.add_hotkey('Up arrow', lambda:
                    forward(2))
keyboard.add_hotkey('Left arrow', lambda:
                    left(2))
keyboard.add_hotkey('right arrow', lambda:
                    right(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we don't need the keboard module to move the turtle around the screen with the keyboard, we can use turtle's own keyboard events:

```
import turtle

turtle.shape("turtle")

turtle.onkey(lambda: turtle.forward(20), "Up")
turtle.onkey(lambda: turtle.left(45), "Left")
turtle.onkey(lambda: turtle.right(45), "Right")

turtle.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Make sure to click on the window to activate it before typing.  If you really want to use the keybard module, this seems to have worked for me:

```
import turtle
import keyboard

turtle.shape("turtle")

keyboard.add_hotkey('up arrow', turtle.forward, args=[20])
keyboard.add_hotkey('left arrow', turtle.left, args=[45])
keyboard.add_hotkey('right arrow', turtle.right, args=[45])

turtle.mainloop()
```

You can also use a `lambda` variant:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('right arrow', lambda: turtle.right(45))
```

Though on my system (OSX) it was difficult to work with (single key press generated multiple events that didn't fire until later key presses, wanted to run as admin, etc.)